# Summing a sequence of numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi Im super new to programming and I dont know how to write a loop which will expand an empty list with a sum of previous numbers  in range(1, 21). So the list should look like this (1 , 1+2 , 1+2+3 etc)

Comment: @miradulo Nah, this is a special case, allowing special solutions.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry can you elaborate? It seems like a clear duplicate to me unless you use partial sums given the sequence form, but that seems like a reach.

Comment: @miradulo That other question is for the general case. Input can be any list. This one is for a special case. Sure, you can use the answers for that other question to solve this one, but *you don't have to*. The specialness might for example allow *simpler* answers.

Comment: @miradulo Not sure what you mean with "use partial sums given the sequence form", btw.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I disagree - that isn't the essence of this question IMHO unless OP further clarifies, but I can see where you're coming from. By partial sums of the sequence I meant you could use the fact that the i-th element in such a list will be i(i+1)/2 instead of doing a regular accumulating sum, but it will be slower anyways. Maybe there's something more clever though.

Comment: @miradulo Yes, that's exactly one example. In fact, `[i*(i+1)//2 for i in range(1, 21)]` might be the shortest possible solution. But you won't find it under that other question. Because there it's not a valid solution.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sure. If we're code golfing then how about `[i*-~i//2 for i in range(1, 21)]` ;). I don't know, agree to disagree I guess - just don't see how this question offers any value to anyone trying to solve a meaningful problem.

Comment: @miradulo Yeah, I wasn't golfing, just wrote it the normal way. For golfing, you should also remove the two unneeded spaces :-). I just added an answer myself, btw, one that also exploits the specialness and can't be used for the other question.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = range(1, 21)
print ([sum(l[:i]) for i in l])
#Output:
#[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, 210]
```

To make it generic to any list, here you go

```
l = [3,4,5,6,7,12] # or l = range(1, 21)
print ([sum(l[:i]) for i in range(1,len(l)+1)])
#Output:
#[3, 7, 12, 18, 25, 37]
```

Comment: This won't work if you change the lower bound on `l` or use a totally different list e.g. `l=[8,4,2]`. I suggest using `range` a second time: `[sum(l[:i+1]) for i in range(len(l))]`

Comment: @Arthur Tacca - my solution is based on OP's input and expected output :)

Comment: Well OK, here's a another valid way of doing it: `result=[1, 3, 6, 10, ...` (you get the idea) :-) My comment gives the same result as your answer but IMO it is a bit clearer because it is not using the values in the list as indices into the same list. Even if it will never be used with a different lower bound, I find it a bit mind boggling.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> MyList = []
>>> for i in range(1 + 1,21):
...   partial_sum = 0
...   for j in range(1,i):
...     partial_sum += j
...   MyList.append(partial_sum)
...
>>> MyList
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190]
```

I'm using `1+1` in the outer `for` loop to prevent a `0` at the beginning of the list. I'm using a sum to put on evidence that I'm thinking of it as `start + 1` rather than a start oint different from 1.

This is *not* the best way to do this, but it is effective and fairly simple to understand, using only simple loops and `range()`. Using `sum()` and/or `reduce()` to produce a nicer solution is possible, but it goes outside the scope of the question.

Comment: What do you mean with "effective"?

Comment: I mean it produces the expected result reliably, given a valid input. I'm looking at this generic definition ( https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/effective ), is it incorrect  or incomplete in the context of programming? Would "working solution" be a more appropriate term?

Comment: I guess you can say that, but it sounds weird. I don't think I've ever seen it used in programming. Why point out that it's "effective" when everybody expects that anyway?

Comment: I wanted to emphasize that my solution works correctly for any valid input, in spite of not being the best solution possible. I did not want to give the impression of posting an incorrect solution for simplicity's sake, which could have come from a poor comment. Thank you for your feedback, I will attempt to be clearer and avoid reduntant information in future answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply recursive approach to this problem:

```
l = []

def expand(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        item = n + expand(n - 1)
        l.append(item)
        return item

expand(21)
print l

[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, 210, 231]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called *prefix sums* or *cumulative sum*. Easily done with `numpy` which is de-facto standard for numeric calcualtions.

```
import numpy as np
data = range(1, 21)
print(np.cumsum(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard library for the win!

```
import itertools
x = range(1, 5)
list(itertools.accumulate(x))
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```